# Ruby: string float to integer

Tags: ruby

I want this:

```
'5.6535'.something => 56
'5.657'.something => 566
'5.3'.something => 530
'5'.something => 500
```

and so on...

My "string" float ranges from `1..9` and I want them to convert to an integer with three digets.

Thanks!

Kieran

Comment: What should the result be if the input is `'56'`?

Comment: Your string always contains only one digit before separator?

Comment: Do you want them to be rounded or just cut off at the end?

Comment: Yes that's right, it ranges from 1..9 so this should work.

Comment: Since when is "56" three digits long?

Comment: there is no input like 56, it's all 1..9 so that wont be a problem.
It is like @WarHog says

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strings.each do |str|
  puts (str.to_f * 100).floor
end
```

Substitute `round` or `ceil` for `floor` depending on what behavior you want with rounding.

Comment: Thanks, it is really that simple!

Found this as well: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-to_f

Comment: This doesn't guarantee three digits.

Comment: @MarkByers, sure. question needs clarification if this matters.

Comment: @MarkByers Just edited the question. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

```
(x + '00­0').scan(/­\d/)[0,3].­join('').to_i
```